# How to map a filter for a portlet in Liferay?

Tags: java, filter, liferay, liferay-6

I just created one filter inside my portlet and I want to execute it when one of the page inside my portlet is getting loaded.

How can I map the filter for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd let us know what you want to achieve, someone might come up with a better way to implement this. For now, you should bind your filter to `/*` and check for the expected URL yourself. Reasons: Liferay can show your page as `/web/guest/my-page-name` in the default language, `/en/web/guest/my-page-name` as an explicitly requested english page, `/my-page-name` when virtual hosting is enabled and the hosts match.

For some (maybe performance?) reasons servlet filter URLs must not start with wildcards, but can end in them. Thus you'll have to work with this limitations if a servlet filter is your tool of choice. As I said above, if we knew what you try to achieve, we might point out a better solution.

Comment: I just want to create a filter for a portlet. Its enough only for the first loading page of the portlet. The filter is created inside the portlet only, I just want to map it for the portlets view page.